# Can't find Split or Combo loan calculation

Tags: loans, home-loan

I have to calculate a split loan calculator.As I know that,Split means combo we are get benefits of both interest type.I have calculated a many things are right but problem with Total Payable interest.

**Update**
what is Total payable interest ? How would I calculate in case for split loan?

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why not calculate interest from each loan then add?

Comment: @PeteB.will you please explain?

Comment: @MichaelC. Question is Total Invest Payable is getting wrong.I want to understand how its work?How should I implement for loan that I borrowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total interest payable in the OP's screenshot: $56, does not match the result calculated below, $28.  However, the other figures do match up.  The $56 result could be due to an error on the web form.  Maybe try again in a refreshed webpage.

The calculation is laid out below.

Source: [Mortgage Choice - Split loan repayments calculator](https://www.mortgagechoice.com.au/home-loans/calculators/split-loan-repayments-calculator.aspx)

[image]

Starting the calculation using the standard repayment formula.

```
s is the principal
rf & rv are the fixed and variable rates
pf is the percentage of the loan that is fixed
sf & sv are the fixed and variable portions of the loan
n is the full term of the loan
df & dv are the fixed and variable repayment during the fixed period

s = 1000
rf = 0.01/12
pf = 0.6

sf = s*pf = 600

n = 2*12 = 24

df = (rf (1 + rf)^n sf)/((1 + rf)^n - 1) = 25.2612

rv = 0.04/12
sv = s (1 - pf)

dv = (rv (1 + rv)^n sv)/((1 + rv)^n - 1) = 17.37
```

The calculation of the fixed and variable repayments (for the fixed period) confirms the method for the initial values being used by the online calculators.

The next step uses a recurrence formula to calculate the balance at the end of the fixed period.  Based on the following expression for the month-to-month loan remaining `m`, a recurrence formula has been calculated.

```
m[nf + 1] = m[nf] pf (1 + rf) - df + m[nf] (1 - pf) (1 + rv) - dv

where m[0] = s
```

With the number of fixed periods `nf = 12` the recurrence formula below gives the total loan remaining at the end of month 12:

```
m[nf] = m[12] =
 (df + dv - (1 + pf (rf - rv) + rv)^nf (df + dv - (pf rf + rv - pf rv) s))/
  (pf (rf - rv) + rv) = 505.459
```

Next, the standard loan formula is used to calculate the repayment `d` for the variable-only portion of the loan.

```
nv = n - nf = 12

d = (m[nf] rv (1 + rv)^nv)/((1 + rv)^nv - 1) = 43.0397
```

Calculating the interest

```
total interest = (df + dv) nf + d nv - s = 28.0516
```

**Running a check with different figures**

Source: [ING Home Loans Calculator](https://www.ing.com.au/home-loans/calculators/split-loan.html)

[image]

Note: further to the OP's question in comments the version below includes alternative calculations for the case where the variable rate of interest is zero.

```
s = 350000
rf = 0.0625/12 
pf = 4.29/100
sf = s*pf
n = 30*12
df = (rf (1 + rf)^n sf)/((1 + rf)^n - 1) = 92.4499

rv = 0.06/12
sv = s (1 - pf)
dv = If[rv == 0,
  sv/n,
  (rv (1 + rv)^n sv)/((1 + rv)^n - 1)] = 2008.4

df + dv = 2100.85

nf = 3*12 = 36

m = If[rv == 0,
  (df + dv - (1 + pf rf)^nf (df + dv - pf rf s))/(pf rf),
  (df + dv - (1 + pf (rf - rv) + rv)^nf (df + dv - (pf rf + rv - pf rv) s))/
   (pf (rf - rv) + rv)] = 336319.61

nv = n - nf = 324

d = If[rv == 0,
  m/nv,
  (m rv (1 + rv)^nv)/((1 + rv)^nv - 1)] = 2098.59

totalinterest = (df + dv) nf + d nv - s = 405572.34
```

Checks out within acceptable calculation precision variation.

Comment: @VasimVanzara The interest itself is easy to calculate as shown in the last line.  However, it was necessary to understand how all the other figures were being calculated in order to be certain as to what they actually represented.

Comment: I have included alternative calculations to handle the case for zero variable interest in the second example, the check calculation.

Comment: No iteration is required. If nf is set to, say 12, m (the loan balance remaining) at the end of month 12 is the result. If rv is zero use m = (df + dv - (1 + pf rf)^nf (df + dv - pf rf s))/(pf rf)

Comment: Please look into have some issue with this calculator https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/84737/extra-repayement-loan-calculator