# Saved Interest & Saved Time is wrong while other calculation is right - Extra Repayement loan calculator

Tags: loans, home-loan

I have create a calculator for loan repayment its working properly.When I create for the extra repayment didn't give a result as I expect.

**Question : Saved Interest & Saved Time is wrong while other calculation is right**

Referance calculator : http://www.homeloans.com.au/calculators/extra-repayments-calculator/

[image: Reference Calculator]

[image: My calculator]

**Result not match with 1619.72**

```
firstpartlog=Math.pow((1 + r),-m)
interestpostive=Math.pow((1 + r),m)

secondpartlog=(-d + d2 + interestpostive *d - (r*s))

n = -(Math.log(firstpartlog*secondpartlog)/d2)/bottomlog))
```

Comment: Seems like there are two possibilities: either your calculator actually is not working right, or your idea of the right answer is wrong.

Comment: @jamesqf it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mathematics for this calculation is explained here:

[What is the formula for calculating the total cost of a loan with extra payments towards the principal?](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/83471/11768)

First calculating for loan without extra repayments

```
n is the number of periods
s is the principal
r is the periodic interest rate
d is the periodic repayment

n = 40*52 = 2080
s = 123500
r = 9/100/52

d = r (1 + 1/(-1 + (1 + r)^n)) s = 219.774
```

Check

```
n = -(Log[1 - (r s)/d]/Log[1 + r]) = 2080

interest = n d - s =  333629.405
```

Now adding `m` and `d2`

```
m is the number of periods after which extra repayments are made
d2 is the repayment including the extra amount

m = 29*52 = 1508
d2 = d + 566 = 785.774
```

The formula for a loan with extra repayment towards the end is

[image]

```
∴ n = -(Log[((1 + r)^-m (-d + d2 + (1 + r)^m (d - r s)))/d2]/Log[1 + r]) = 1619.72
```

With the extra repayment the loan is repaid in `1619.72/51 = 31.15 years`.  Treatment of the incomplete week is up to the lender, who may require a larger payment on week 1619 to complete repayment or take a smaller repayment in week 1620.  (This can slightly affect the total interest.)

```
interest = m d + (n - m) d2 - s =  295703.813

interest saving = 333629.405 - 295703.813 = 37925.59
```

Rounded to the dollar the saving calculate with a partial week is 37926.

**Comparison with website results**

8 year 10 months is `(8*12) + 10 = 106 months`

40 year loan less 106 months is `40*12 - 106 = 374 months`

Calculated term is `1619.72*12/52 = 373.782 months`

Website interest saved is 37925.

**Amortization amortization table**

Using an amortization table calculates the interest saving minutely differently due to the treatment of the incomplete week.  In the table the final week's balance is held for the full week whereas the formula uses a fraction of a week for a linear solution.

Saving by formula:  `2080 d - (m d + (n - m) d2) = 37925.59`

Amortization table: `2080 d - s - 295703.950225  = 37925.46`

*Amortization table showing figures and formulas*

[image]

**Whole final week calculation without amortisation table**

The following calculates the interest saving assuming the final week carries a whole week's interest and matches the website, (rounded to the dollar).

```
n = 40*52 = 2080
s = 123500
r = 9/100/52
d = r (1 + 1/(-1 + (1 + r)^n)) s = 219.774
```

interest for loan with no extra payments

```
i1 = n d - s = 333629.405
```

increased payment

```
d2 = d + 566
```

number of week at initial payment `d`

```
m = 1508
```

time needed to repay (as linear calculation)

```
n = -(Log[((1 + r)^-m (-d + d2 + (1 + r)^m (d - r s)))/d2]/Log[1 + r]) = 1619.72
```

number of whole weeks

```
n2 = 1619
```

present value of amount repaid up to and including week 1508

```
s2 = (d - d (1 + r)^-m)/r = 117621.856
```

present value remaining

```
s3 = s - s2 = 5878.144
```

future value of remainder at week 1508

```
s4 = s3 (1 + r)^m =  79757.043
```

number of weeks from 1508 to 1619

```
n3 = 1619 - 1508 = 111
```

amount paid by d2 in 111 weeks

```
s5 = (d2 - d2 (1 + r)^-n3)/r = 79292.149
```

future value remaining in week 1508

```
s6 = s4 - s5 = 464.894
```

future value remaining in week 1619 (note this matches the amortisation table)

```
s7 = s6 (1 + r)^n3 = 563.2699
```

interest from week 1619 to week 1620

```
i3 = s7 r = 0.97489
```

interest paid with extra payments

```
i2 = m d + n3 d2 + s7 + i3 - s =  295703.950
```

interest saving

```
i1 - i2 = 37925.455
```

Rounded to the dollar, 37925.

**Addendum re. zero interest rate**

When the interest rate is zero the standard loan equation becomes

[image]

```
∴ d = s/n
```

and the equation for a loan with extra payments becomes

[image]

```
∴ n = (s + d2 m - d m)/d2
```

Rerunning the calculation as described above

```
n = 40*52
s = 123500
r = 0
d = s/n = 59.375

i1 = n d - s = 0
d2 = d + 566
m = 1508
n = (s + d2 m - d m)/d2 = 1562.307

n2 = 1562
s2 = d m = 89537.5
s3 = s - s2 = 33962.5
s4 = s3 (1 + r)^m = 33962.5
n3 = 1562 - 1508 = 54
s5 = d2 n3 = 33770.25
s6 = s4 - s5 = 192.25
s7 = s6 (1 + r)^n3 = 192.25
i3 = s7 r = 0
i2 = m d + n3 d2 + s7 + i3 - s = 0
i1 - i2 = 0
```

Comment: In your amortization table the balance remaining for week 1508 should be `balance for week 1507 * (1 + r) - d  =  79838.63 (1 + r) - d =  79757.04` but the balance for the next week, 1509 should be `balance for week 1508 * (1 + r) - d2  =  79757.04 (1 + r) - d2 =  79109.31`.  The balance for week 0 is 123500 and the balance for week 1619 is 563.27.

Comment: `week 0 balance = 123500`, `week 1 balance = week 0 balance * (1 + r) - d`, `week 2 balance = week 1 balance * (1 + r) - d` and so on up to week 1508 where d changes to d2.

Comment: When I use this it goes in minus

Comment: @VasimVanzara It is all shown in the amortisation table. The balance remaining is positive until week 1619, then it is paid down to zero with a reduced final repayment of 564.24.

Comment: I have accept your answer as well as bounty also added after 1 day to your account

Comment: Jolly good. It was interesting figuring it out.

Comment: Please look into this acutally not understand transfer fee : https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/85128/calculate-stamp-duty-transfer-fee-qld